# How to get focus or click inside the body of the iframe using capybara - rspec

Tags: iframe, rspec, triggers, focus, capybara

I'm trying to test a wysihtml5 editor. The user will click on the editor (revealing the editor controls) and start typing. This will reveal more fields to fill.

This all functions as expected, but I'm trying to set up the capybara script to replicate this user flow.

- I need to focus inside the iframe body to get the fields ul and div above the iframe to show.
- Then I need to type (trigger keyup) inside the iframe body (which should then load more fields onto the page).

This is the structure:

```
<div class="wysiwyg-textarea">
    <ul id="prompt-content-12345-wysihtml5-toolbar" >
    <textarea id="prompt-content-12345"  >
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="_wysihtml5_mode" >
    <div>
    <iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox"  >
        <html>
            <body class="no-border placeholder-as-label initials-title wysihtml5-editor placeholder" contenteditable="true" > …..
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried the following and I keep getting the error mentioned below:

Scripts:

```
#page.execute_script("parent.focus()")
#page.execute_script %Q{ $("self.editor.body.focus()")}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $(document).ready(.focus)}
#find(:xpath, "//form/div/div/div/div/iframe").click
#page.execute_script %Q{ $("//form/div[id='magic-box-prompts']").focus() }
#page.execute_script("editor.focus()")
#page.execute_script %Q{ $("body").trigger("click")}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $(iframe.contentWindow.focus()}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $(.contentWindow.focus()}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $(this.iframe.contentWindow.document.body.focus()}
#page.driver.browser.frame_focus('iframe')
#var editor_body = (".wysihtml5-sandbox").document.body
#page.execute_script %Q{ $(editor_body).keyup(function() { console.log($(this).text()) }) }
#find('.ta-wrapper.wysiwyg-textarea').click
#page.execute_script %Q{ $('.wysiwyg-textarea').trigger()}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $('.wysiwyg-textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('this is a text') }
#page.execute_script %Q{ $('body.no-border.placeholder-as-label.mb-title.wysihtml5-editor.placeholder', $('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).on('keyup')}
#page.execute_script %Q{$('iframe').contents().find('body').attr('contenteditable', true).on( 'keyup',function() { }) }
#page.execute_script %Q{$(".mb-input").focus().trigger('keyup')}
#page.execute_script %Q{$('body.wysihtml5-editor', $('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents()).trigger('keyup')}
#page.execute_script %Q{ $("window.editor.composer.element").focus().trigger("keyup") }
```

Errors:

```
Failure/Error: *name of the script*
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
       $(...) is null
```